# C# read only multidimensional array and tilemaps

Tags: c#, arrays, tile

I made a tile map class, that only contains the data and methods to get or set tiles.
Now I have the problem, that I want to make a tile map renderer.
But I thing its not very fast to call the methods GetTile(int layerIndex, int x, int y); to iterate threw the tiles and draw them.
So I want to give the possibility to get the full array with all data.
In this case tiledMapData.
But the problem is, that I want that someone cant change the values of the array, because I want make events for changing tiles for physics.
How I can do this.

```
public class TiledMap
{
    public int LayerCount
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public int TileCountX
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public int TileCountY
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public int TotalTileCount
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    private int[,] tiledMapData;


    public TiledMap(int layerCount, int tileCountX, int tileCountY)
    {
        LayerCount = layerCount;
        TileCountX = tileCountX;
        TileCountY = tileCountY;
        TotalTileCount = TileCountX * TileCountY;

        tiledMapData = new int[LayerCount, TotalTileCount];
        for (int layerIndex = 0; layerIndex < TotalTileCount; layerIndex++)
        {
            for (int tileIndex = 0; tileIndex < TotalTileCount; tileIndex++)
            {
                tiledMapData[layerIndex, tileIndex] = 0;
            }
        }
    }


    public int  GetTile(int layerIndex, int x, int y)
    {
        return tiledMapData[layerIndex, y * TileCountX + x];
    }
    public void SetTile(int layerIndex, int x, int y, int tileType)
    {
        tiledMapData[layerIndex, y * TileCountX + x] = tileType;
    }
}
```

And generally, how you would design a tilemap 100 x 100 tiles 16 bit graphics and destroy able/build able tiles, how handle physics player interaction and so on....?
Maybe someone know good tutorials(The language is not important)

Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Could you simply duplicate the data and return that duplicate?

Comment: you can possibly use jaggard array http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

Comment: Because of the array optimization @toATwork pointed out in my revoked answer I guess this direct access is the most performant one. I guess (without testing) that every kind of ReadOnlyCollection even if made multi-dimensional could not match with the pure aray performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I have to reject this, it makes a difference event when not using Length directly.

```
        const int countX = 100;
        const int countY = 100;
        const int countLayer = 5;
        TiledMap tm = new TiledMap(countLayer, countX, countY);

        const int testRuns = 10000;

        Console.WriteLine("Run 1, start");
        DateTime start1 = DateTime.Now;
        for (int test = 0; test < testRuns; test++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < countLayer; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < countX; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < countY; k++)
                    {
                        int data = tm.GetTile(i, j, k);
                        data++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        DateTime end1 = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Run 1, time: {0}", end1-start1));

        Console.WriteLine("Run 2, start");
        DateTime start2 = DateTime.Now;
        for (int test = 0; test < testRuns; test++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < countLayer; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < countX; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < countY; k++)
                    {
                        int data = tm.DirectArray[i, k*countX + j];
                        data++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        DateTime end2 = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Run 1, time: {0}", end2 - start2));

        Console.ReadLine();
```

The array access variant performed much better. Still not sure if it would when you use some kind of *read only array*. So make sure you check it out.

Comment: That is simply not corret! If you directly access an array (jagged as well but NOT multi dimensional) with a for loop such as `for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)` (important the Length property!) the bounds check will be done only once instead of for each access! That can make a huge difference!

Comment: You would not need `Length`. The object above has fixed counts of layers, X and Y. I am doing a performance check project...

Comment: I did a performance check - and an intense read on the documentation. With Array and the Length operator they do some internal optimization - as mentionend before, e.g. bounds check only once at the beginning of the loop and not for each access in the loop.

Comment: @toATwork You are right and the optimization applies also when not using Length by yourself. He just knows it is an array.

Comment: @toATwork Thanks for pointing out. Every day is learning day ;)

Comment: You are mostly welcome! PS: in my performance comparision that jagged array `[][]` performed best.